# What is the part of a method signature in C++ between the ending parenthesis and beginning curly bracket?

Tags: c++, methods, syntax, signature

I'm starting to learn C++ and there's some syntax in method signatures I haven't seen before. Here's an example:

```
const char * what() const throw() { return msg; }
```

what is the "const throw()" part for? I haven't seen anything where there is stuff between the method name/parameters and the curly brackets.

Comment: @user3390855 I think const here is for symmetry only.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are specifiers. They describes how the method works in the coding environment

`const` means that the method will NOT modify the object. If you have a class `A`, all methods can be run on an object of type `A` but only `const` methods can be run on an object of type `const A`.

If you try to run a non-const method on a const object, or if you try to modify an object from a const method, your code will not compile and the compiler will tell say that you did something wrong.

`throw()` means that the method will not throw an exception. It as been replaced by `noexcept` since C++11.

Including such keywords when needed is, as far as I'm concerned, a very good thing.  It adds descriptions on the expected behaviour to the code itself and helps get clearer compiler errors when you do something wrong.

It also helps the compiler do some optimizations.

Comment: `throw()` means the opposite of that, and it should be replaced with `noexcept` in C++11 and up.

Comment: No, `throw()` means that the method will not throw any exception at all. E.g. `throw(A,B)` would mean that the method would throw only exceptions of type `A` and `B`. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Your edit was completely wrong, `throw()` means the function will not throw anything

Comment: @Praetorian I just did edit by means of the wrongly used _return_, exceptions aren't returned, but thrown. I agree with your critiques about the behavioral semantics description, but that goes to the OP. Well, we can turn a wrong answer into a correct one by just adding a single word ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well then you didn't do [what you intended](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29020485/2) - *`throw()` means that the method may throw an exception. Calling code should be prepared for that possibility*. Amxx: I'm not sure whether `throw()` has been deprecated in favor of `noexcept`. `throw(types, that, could, be, thrown)` has definitely been deprecated.

Comment: `const` on a member function is a promise that the function will not change the observable public state of that object. It is still allowed to change internal private state through the use of the `mutable` qualifier.

Comment: @Praetorian I swear, my edit was only about that single word. Unfortunately it seems having been merged with another edit, I didn't see at this time.

Comment: @Praetorian `throw()` is also deprecated.